# Django ignore TemplateSyntaxError. Vue Syntax

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm building a pwa on top of django.

In the pwa.html I use valid vue syntax:

```
{{ counter() }}
```

or

```
 {{ el| removehtml() | truncate(40) }}
```

Works flawless in a non Django project.

I get an TemplateSyntaxError on runserver, how can I ignore this, cause this is valid for vue syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 solutions:

either in vue with delimiters:

```
el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data: {
    message: ...
  }
```

...

than in template `[[ vuefunc() ]]` instead of default `{{ vuefunct() }}`

or with django verbatim

```
{% verbatim %}

    {{ vuefunct() }}
      
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Django does not use Jinja. It has its own template syntax, explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/) in the documentation.

> If you have any exposure to other text-based template languages, such
> as Smarty or Jinja2, you should feel right at home with Django’s
> templates.

The syntax may look like Jinja, but the functions could be different.